# P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 when trying to access an OpenVPN server

Tags: openvpn

I would like to connect to an OpenVPN server from an Ubuntu host which also serves as the firewall for other internal connections (two APs and several virtual machines running on that server).

My connection hangs at

```
Sat Nov 19 22:09:41 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]185.145.38.234:1194
Sat Nov 19 22:10:41 2016 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Sat Nov 19 22:10:41 2016 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Sat Nov 19 22:10:41 2016 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Sat Nov 19 22:10:41 2016 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
```

A `tcpdump`of the connection shows that

```
root@srv ~# tcpdump -i any host 185.145.38.234
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
22:35:38.933443 IP 192.168.0.10.41552 > 185.145.38.234.openvpn: UDP, length 42
22:35:40.116782 IP 192.168.0.10.41552 > 185.145.38.234.openvpn: UDP, length 42
22:35:44.849548 IP 192.168.0.10.41552 > 185.145.38.234.openvpn: UDP, length 42
```

I can connect from the same prompt to any service, all traffic is allowed. When trying to specifically connect to that port I get

```
root@srv ~# nc -v -u 185.145.38.234 1194
Connection to 185.145.38.234 1194 port [udp/openvpn] succeeded!
```

I have the same behaviour for `tcp` OpenVPN connections (including the successful `nc`).

The first reason I can think of for such behaviour (client sends a request and does not get anything back) is wrong routing or firewalling. But any other connection from the same system (same prompt, a `curl www.google.com` for instance) succeeds. There is no firewalling from that place (the traffic is completely open).

Another reason could be some filtering upstream (of the ISP). This is not the case either as a client on the LAN (which transits through the machine above and ultimately exits though the same interface) can connect successfully.

What could be an other reason for this message and connection failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow late but the reason was that an **adaptative** firewall was blocking the traffic as soon as it "recognized" it as OpenVPN (probably based on specific packets)

Answer (score 0):

For pfSense users

For some reason, in the OpenVPN Server you have to set the interface as any, not WAN